# How to force https in CakePHP without redirect from http?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to use https for my CakePHP application.

I found some articles explain how to force https in CakePHP ( http://blog.andolasoft.com/2013/07/ssl-authentication-using-security-component-in-cakephp.html )

But the problem is I'm using load balancer (AWS), so I faced with the problem if I use redirect (redirect loop).

Would anyone have experience with this issue?

How to force https in CakePHP without redirect from http ?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Probably gonna be a server setting, not a Cake thing.

Comment: "aws load balancer force https" - [first result from Google](http://www.emind.co/how-to/how-to-force-https-behind-aws-elb)

Answer (score 2):

I use CakePHP 2 on server without https, but with activated cloudflare (with https). So CloudFlare give me https to the end user. This is what I have added to my /app/webroot/index.php to make it work:

```
function isSSL(){
    if( !empty( $_SERVER['https'] ) )
        return true;
    if( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' )
        return true;
    return false;
}

define('IS_IN_PRODUCTION', 1);
if( !isSSL() && IS_IN_PRODUCTION > 0){
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

I hope this can help!

Comment: is `define('IS_IN_PRODUCTION', 0);` must be `1` when deploying to production env?

Comment: Yes, IS_IN_PRODUCTION must be 1 to be active.

Comment: This also works in CakePHP 3. All of the other methods I've read about caused a redirect loop on my production host. Thanks!!

Comment: Another option might be to use a separate config file that is required as index.php is not ignored by git by default.